# Showing that metric induces single unique topology on a finite set

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove, that given a metric on a finite set it induces exactly one topology. I have an idea which might lead to a proof, but am not sure:

For a finite set X with a given metric d we can prove it is a discrete topology:

$\forall x \in X$ take $r$ s.t. $ r := \min_{y \in X}(d(x, y))$. We can do this as $X$ is finite. This way we can construct open balls for each $x$ such that they contain only x. So each x is in a open subset which is a singleton. And therefore we have a discrete topology.

I am not sure how to proceed showing that it is only this topology that we can get from the metric space.

Thank you.

Comment: didn't you just prove that's the only topology you can get?

Comment: I do not know how to rigorously prove it is the only one. As from the question it seems that for infinite sets one can get many topologies using the same metric.

Comment: It's the other way round: There can be several metrics which induce the same topology. \\ Since you have started with an arbitrary metric on the set $X$, I would say your done with your proof.

Comment: Your argument shows that any metric defined on a finite set will induce the discrete topology on that set. Therefore, the discrete topology is the only one that can be induced by a metric on a finite set.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is fine, except that you want your minimum to run only over $y\in X\setminus\{x\}$.

[Note that this proof (of course) fails for infinite $X$ as the minimum of infinitely many positive numbers  need not exist (or, if we switch to the infimum, it need no longer be positive).]

Answer (score 0):

No matter finite sets or other general sets,the induced topology exists uniquely.Specially,the induced topology of finite set equipped with arbitrary metric is the discrete topology,more,unique.